# How to get a Stream from an XMLWriter?

Tags: .net, stream, xmlwriter

An instance of [System.Xml.XmlWriter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlwriter.aspx) is writing to an underlying Stream right ?(regardless of what the specific implementation of the XmlWriter is)

So how come there are no methods available for a programmer to retrieve the Stream object from the XmlWriter?

I'm sure I am missing something simple. Thanks in advance.

PS: In case anyone asks, what I really want to do is get the stream from an XmlWriter instance passed to me, and create an XmlReader from it (flush the Writer first if needs be).

I then need to use the XmlReader as a parameter to [XslCompiledTransform.Transform](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.xml.xsl.xslcompiledtransform.transform%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) method

Edit: punctuation

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**You should not do it**. Even though you know that `XmlWriter` has some `Stream` underneath but this is implementation detail and `XmlWriter` should not give it to you. Also stream may readonly or writeonly, how will you read from it?

You should pass original stream that was used to instantiate `XmlWriter` to the place where you want to read the stream if you know that stream can be both written and read. Otherwise you should create a new stream which will read the content written by `XmlWriter`.

Comment: > You should not do it. 

It seems I cant anyway. But your explanation makes sense: There is no guarantee the stream can be read from. Thanks for that.

> Otherwise you should create a new stream which will read the content written by XmlWriter.

I am still struggling with how to do this though?

Comment: @K_M, it depends on how do you create that stream for `XmlWriter` - this is the key point here.

Comment: JIM-compiler,


I am passed an instance of XmlWriter and so I will not know in advance how the Stream was created.
Perhaps the design is flawed.

But just so I get it straight - it is not possible to get a Stream (new or otherwise) from just an XmlWriter then?
Which means, given an XmlWriter, there is no way to create an XmlReader with the same data? (Sorry I am going off topic. Let me know if its against the etquette here at stackoverflow). Thanks for your replies so far.

Comment: @K_M, do not think it is that much an off-topic. You can try casting passed `XmlWriter` to its real implementation class (`XmlWriter` is abstract), you will have to know what implementations of `XmlWriter` may be passed to you. Some `XmlWriter` inheritors, for example `XmlTextWriter`, expose passed stream (`XmlTextWriter.BaseStream` property), you can try it, I haven't tried. This will be a major hack, but if you really need it...

Comment: JIM-compiler, 

It makes sense for me to only accept XmlTextWriter rather than it's baseclass XmlWriter. From there I am able to use the BaseStream property, and create a new XmlReader from it. Problem solved. Thanks!