# Convert XmlWriter to Stream / char / byte []

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, blazor, client-side

I have an asp.net/C#/Blazor environment, where a button generates an XML with a specific class. With XML Writer, I can make the file, and even can save/download it, but it goes to the server-side (It **must** to be downloaded on client-side. please, do not argue about it).

I know Blazor implemented some instant download (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/file-downloads?view=aspnetcore-6.0) and it works perfect with blank/new files, but the problem is, I don't know how to "pass" or convert my previously generated XML with XML Writer method, because Blazor method(s) only allow Stream, char or byte Arrays downloads.

When I tried to convert it, the error

Some of my code is:

```
    protected async Task CreateXmlFile(int correlativo,string idDocumento, string siglaDocumento, List<DocumentoXML> documentos = null, List<SignersXML> signersXMLs = null,
                                                                                                              List<ContentXMLComplemento> complementos = null,
                                                                                                              List<SignersXMLComplemento> signersComplemento = null)
{
    _xmlWriterSettings = new XmlWriterSettings
        {
            Indent = true,
            Encoding = new UTF8Encoding(false)
        };

    string fullPath= "";
    XmlWriter writer;
    XmlSerializer serializer;

        var documentoIngresoRaiz = new DocumentoIngresoRaiz
            {
                Content_XML = new List<ContentXML>
                {
                    new ContentXML
                    {
                        sve_XML = new List<sveXML>
                        {
                           new sveXML
                           {
                               Documento_XML = documentos
                           }
                        }
                    }
                },
                Signers_XML = signersXMLs
            };

        fullPath = $"{mainPath}Ingreso-{correlativo}.xml";
        var fileName = $"Ingreso-{correlativo}.xml";

        writer = XmlWriter.Create(fullPath, _xmlWriterSettings);
        serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(DocumentoIngresoRaiz));
        serializer.Serialize(writer, documentoIngresoRaiz);
        writer.Close(); 

    //I've been trying with these 3 Blazor method lines, to send my xml as stream
    var fileStream = new MemoryStream(writer);
    using var streamRef = new DotNetStreamReference(stream: fileStream);
    await JS.InvokeVoidAsync("downloadFileFromStream", fileName, streamRef);
}
```

> Error CS1503: Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Xml.XmlWriter' to 'byte[]'

I've been looking all around StackOverflow and the Internet with no success.
I found some similar posts ([I want to download XML file in C# which I created using XmlWriter.Create() on user's system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59196104/i-want-to-download-xml-file-in-c-sharp-which-i-created-using-xmlwriter-create)) ([How to get a Stream from an XMLWriter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5486129/how-to-get-a-stream-from-an-xmlwriter)), but they couldn't solve my problem. Any help or tip is welcome. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Can't you just serialize directly to a `MemoryStream` via `XmlWriter.Create(stream, _xmlWriterSettings);`?

Comment: @dbc yeah, I already tried that, but same error appears: "cannot convert from 'System.Xml.XmlWriter' to 'char[]' :/

Comment: What line does the compilation error occur on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since there was no way to convert the already generated XML file to byte/stream/char array, I found out that the solution was:

saving this XML file on server-side
and then immediately download it to local machine, via JavaScript code (pasted below), passing the fileURL (location of file on the server) and fileName (name of the file)

```
await JS.InvokeVoidAsync("triggerFileDownload", fileName, fileURL);
    
function triggerFileDownload(fileName, url) {
     const anchorElement = document.createElement('a');
     anchorElement.href = url;
     anchorElement.download = fileName ?? '';
     anchorElement.click();
     anchorElement.remove();
 }
```